# Can't display array in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a problem , I found this code and want to display the result (counts) as 
bar graph inside Tkinter or PyQt. It should display window and inside there must be matplotlib bar graph.
There are some useless (For now) imports of TKinter.

```
import menu as menu
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
from scipy.misc import face
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
from tkinter import *




REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE = True

# borrow a list of named colors from matplotlib
if REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE:
    use_colors = {
        k: colors.cnames[k]
        for k in ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'purple']
    }
else:
    use_colors = colors.cnames

# translate hexstring to RGB tuple
named_colors = {
    k: tuple(map(int, (v[1:3], v[3:5], v[5:7]), 3 * (16, )))
    for k, v in use_colors.items()
}
ncol = len(named_colors)

if REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE:
    ncol -= 1
    no_match = named_colors.pop('purple')
else:
    no_match = named_colors['purple']

# make an array containing the RGB values
color_tuples = list(named_colors.values())
color_tuples.append(no_match)
color_tuples = np.array(color_tuples)

color_names = list(named_colors)
color_names.append('no match')

# get example picture
img = face()

# build tree
tree = KDTree(color_tuples[:-1])
# tolerance for color match inf means use best match no matter how
# bad it may be
tolerance = np.inf
# find closest color in tree for each pixel in picture
dist, idx = tree.query(img, distance_upper_bound=tolerance)
# count and reattach names
counts = dict(zip(color_names, np.bincount(idx.ravel(), None, ncol + 1)))

print(counts)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Information about how you've tried to display the bar graph would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your PYQT5 Code.

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QValueAxis, QBarCategoryAxis, QBarSet, QBarSeries
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
def draw_chart():

    main_list = [20,30,5,10,100,70]
    return_list = [100,70,30,5,1,10]

    set0 = QBarSet('Sale Amount')
    set1 = QBarSet('Return Amount')

    set0.append(main_list)
    set1.append(return_list)

    series = QBarSeries()
    series.append(set0)
    series.append(set1)


    chart = QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.setTitle('SALE AND RETURN CHART')
    chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

    months = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May','Jun')

    axisX = QBarCategoryAxis()
    axisX.append(months)

    axisY = QValueAxis()
    axisY.setRange(0, 1000)

    chart.addAxis(axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)
    chart.addAxis(axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)

    chart.legend().setVisible(True)
    chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

    self.chartView = QChartView(chart)
    self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.chartView, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

If you still need any help, Do ask me.

Comment: You should add some explanation of what you have done. Code only answers do not provide much value.